# Java error cannot find symbol variable: id

Tags: android, android-tabhost

im learning how to make Android apps, but I'm stuck with this error and I can't figure it out.

This is what i have in my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

And the part in my code where I'm having problems is:

```
Resources res = getResources();

tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabs.setup();

TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec.setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_my_calendar));
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

It gives me the following error in the spec.setContent(R.id.tab1) line: cannot find symbol : variable id.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have errors in your xml file ? Is R.java re-generated ? Try to clean and build your project

Comment: Thanks for the answers but I fixed it using a try/catch in another part of the code, I feel stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `android.R.id.tabhost`. Import R file of your application instead of `android.R` and use `R.id.tabhost`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your layout xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
             <TabWidget
                 android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="251dp" />
             <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```